# Tkinter Textbox is Backwards

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make my first GUI with tkinter. I have successfully make my text box and file browse button and the basic functionality is there, but my text is being output into the text box upside down.

I've tried changing the line `Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nTransfer to wifi selection page")` to `Text_Box.insert('end', "\nTransfer to wifi selection page")` but that has not worked.

```
# Zack Garris
# 1-28-2019
# SQL to readable text
#add a time stamp!!
import _sqlite3
import re
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from _sqlite3 import Error
import _sqlite3

def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        conn = _sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return None

###########################################
try:
    UserFile = open("UserFriend.txt", "w")
                                            #Check for File if one does not exist make it
except:
    UserFile = open("UserFriend.txt", "w+")
###########################################

global Error
Error = False


#type1 = "Crash"
#type2 = "Connection Issue"

#cause1 = "Possible too far away"
#cause2 = "Poor connection with router with eiter phone or appliance"

def Friendly_Output(line,number,times):
    # Begin Searching
    #print(line, number)
    ############################################################################
    if "viewDidLoad() - Got a valid" in line and Error == False:
        UserFile.write("\nFound mac address here")
        Text_Box.insert("1.0", "\nFound mac address here")
    else:
        pass
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "wifiScanTimerEvent(timer:)" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nPinged nearby wifi with NIC " + str(times) + " time(s)")
        Text_Box.insert("1.0", "\nPinged nearby wifi with NIC " + str(times) + " time(s)")
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "refrigeratorTapped()" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nTransfer to Pin Entry")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nTransfer to Pin Entry")
    else:
        pass
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "applianceTapped() - segue_to_wifi_select_sid" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nTransfer to wifi selection page")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nTransfer to wifi selection page")
    else:
        pass
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "prepare(for:sender:) - segue_to_prod_wifi_setup_sid" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nTransfer to Wifi crediental entry screen")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nTransfer to Wifi crediental entry screen")
    else:
        pass
    if Error == False and "addWifiNameToParamOut(wifi:)" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nAdded wifi to data send list")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nAdded wifi to data send list")
    else:
        pass
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - Called with" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nSent MacAddress, apiKey, and devicePin to Cloud")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nSent MacAddress, apiKey, and devicePin to Cloud")
    else:
        pass
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and r"setDevicePrivilegeCloud(macAddress:userApiKey:devicePin:privilegeCompletionHandler:) - \nDevice" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nSuccessful sending of  MacAddress, apiKey, and devicePin to Cloud")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nSuccessful sending of  MacAddress, apiKey, and devicePin to Cloud")
    else:
        pass
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "onRecordButton" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nEntry applied to appliance list (Continue Button)")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nEntry applied to appliance list (Continue Button)")
    else:
        pass
        ########################################################
    '''
    if Error == False and "updateApplianceRecord() - upda" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nUser notified of success")
    else:
        pass
    '''
        ########################################################
    if Error == False and "updateApplianceRecord() - upda" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nUser notified of success")
        UserFile.write("\nEnd of Setup number: " + str(number) + "\n\n")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nUser notified of success\nEnd of Setup number: " + str(number) + "\n\n")
    else:
        pass

    #while "waitTimerSerialNumEvent" in line and limit < 1:
    #    pass
#setupChangeNotification() - Calling
                #ERROR GRAB
################################################################################

    if   "0110" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: No Bluetooth device was found")
        Text_Box.insert('1.4',"\nERROR: No Bluetooth device was found")
    elif "0120" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: No Wifi or Poor Connection")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: No Wifi or Poor Connection")
    elif "0130" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: User searched for appliance but none was found")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: User searched for appliance but none was found")
    elif "300" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: Wifi List is empty. Restarting configure process.")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: Wifi List is empty. Restarting configure process.")
    elif "310" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: Lost BluetoothConnection in Wifi Picker Screen. Restarting configure process.")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: Lost BluetoothConnection in Wifi Picker Screen. Restarting configure process.")
    elif "1010" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: User opted to skip wifi Setup")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: User opted to skip wifi Setup")
    elif "1011" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: There was an empty text field when trying to configure wifi")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: There was an empty text field when trying to configure wifi")
    elif "1012" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: Bluetooth Disconnected, Reason Unknown")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: Bluetooth Disconnected, Reason Unknown")
    elif "1013" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: The provision watchdog timer has timed out without response from NIC")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: The provision watchdog timer has timed out without response from NIC")
    elif "1029"  in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: The Cloud Service reports error. Error in log")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: The Cloud Service reports error. Error in log")
    elif "1030" in line:
        UserFile.write("\nERROR: The provisioning has failed.  The device and apikey key were not returned")
        Text_Box.insert('1.0', "\nERROR: The provisioning has failed.  The device and apikey key were not returned")

################################################################################
def main(filename):

    list = create_connection(filename)  # create_connection(database)
    global Error
    cur = list.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT error_text from error_log ")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    count = 0
    pings = 1
    hits = 0
    info = []
    for row in rows:
        info.append(row)
#Regex Grab
#########################################################################
    m = re.search(r"(?s)id: (?P<username>.+?) - (?P<password>.+?)'.*Appliance: (?P<modelnumber>\S+).*macAddress: (?P<macaddress>.+?)'.*appl name: (?P<applname>\S+)", str(info))
    if (info):
        try:
            UserFile.write('Username: {}, Password: {}, Modelnumber: {}, Macaddress: {}, applname: {}\n\n'.format(m.group('username'),m.group('password'),m.group('modelnumber'),m.group('macaddress'),m.group('applname')))
            for row in rows:

                Friendly_Output(str(row), count, pings)
                info.append(row)
                if "onRecordButton - Calling" in str(row):
                    count = count + 1
                    pings = 1
                if "wifiScanTimerEvent(timer:)" in str(row):
                    pings = pings + 1
        except:
            print("Type None Occured")





# GUI
################################################################################
window = tk.Tk()

window.title("SQL to Text")
window.geometry("450x1000+225+500")

def Load_File():
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("SQL Database", "*.db"), ("All Files","*.*")))
    main(fname)
    #Text_Output()

#Label
label = tk.Label(text="Click Here to Browse")
label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)



#Browse_Button
Browse_Button = tk.Button(text = "Click Me!", command = Load_File)
Browse_Button.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

#Text field
Text_Box = tk.Text(height = 50, width = 50, background = "black", foreground = "white")
Text_Box.grid(column = 0, row = 2)



window.mainloop()



############################################################################################
```

Comment: It should be `'end'`. You sure you changed every insert command to indicate the end index?

Comment: I changed it on a few to test and did not get an output to the text box.